# Where can I find the specs for the engines of the Curiosity rover?

Tags: astronomy, nasa

I've been looking all over the internet and I cannot find the specific details on the engine of the Curiosity rover. I would need the specifics such as the type of engine, torque, force, rpm, and so on.

Does anybody know where I can find this information?

Comment: They don't have engines.  They have motors.  This question already has an answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/the-types-of-motors-used-on-the-martian-rovers

Comment: That's only a partial answer, doesn't provide any specifications.