# Why did Spirit (MER-A) lose a wheel?

Tags: nasa, curiosity, opportunity, spirit, mars-exploration-rover

I was watching a documentary called Expedition Mars: Spirit and Opportunity (It's really good, I recommend it, you can find it on Disney+) and it said Spirit lost control of its frontmost right side wheel, how did this happen? was it a dust related issue, a age related issue, or a power related one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> No explanation has been established for the
> wheel failure, although a motor brush
> failure is one possibility.

Source: [Mars Exploration Rover Spirit
End of Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20160001767/downloads/20160001767.pdf)

Comment: I started wondering why they didn't use brushless, and of course [that's already been answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/the-types-of-motors-used-on-the-martian-rovers).

Comment: @Bob thanks for the link! I see in the comments that the wheel failure is mentioned there as well.

Comment: @Bob so I looked back on this question, and this is pretty old now, but I decided to do more research on the subject. I found some contradicting sources but one of the most common things I saw it that the current theory is an age-related brush failure. So brushless would've been better, but like you link states, the 90-sol requirement isn't enough to justify brushed motors. I've asked another question, take a look, https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60754/is-a-re-usable-cygnus-possible